# Chat Conversation bot with an API? (cleverbot)

Tags: java, bots

I am looking for an opensource conversation bot or any online bot with an API. I looked at cleverbot, but he sends messages via javascript so idk how to parse it. I have found MegaHal and a java realisation JMegaHal but it is a bit stupid, really. ANy others?

Comment: On a side note. I looked at the data cleverbot sends back and forth, and I don't see any problem in parsing that at all. Their just plain text for crying out loud, followed by a set prefix, then all the messages sent previously.

Comment: @Alxandr I used httpfox to see what is in GET, it showed nothing. Gonna try another parser now. Thanks.

Comment: Just use Google Chrome or Firefox with firebug.

Comment: @Alxandr I am trying to play with apache HttpCLient but can't manage, how do I get the data servers sends to me, if it is in COntent header?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have never used apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at this project [chatter-bot-api](https://github.com/pierredavidbelanger/chatter-bot-api)

This library allows to interact with Cleverbot in JAVA.

Hope this helps!

PS: I am the owner

EDIT: link to GitHub instead of the (now deprecated) Google Code page

Comment: I was searching for this alot. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Love it! Is the `PANDORABOTS` argument (`d689f7b8de347251`) a key specific to you are can anyone use it?

Comment: The pandorabots web site hosts many bots. So the `PANDORABOTS` argument `"d689f7b8de347251"` is the `botid`. Please have a look at this page: [mostactive pandorabots](http://www.pandorabots.com/botmaster/en/mostactive). You will find the list of the most active bots, if you click on one, you will be able to locate its `botid` into the URL.

Comment: Looks like the Cleverbot folks got wind of this and the code has been taken down. Anybody know any alternative libraries?

Comment: @Pierre-DavidBelanger  so ... can i use pandorabots directly if get the botid ?

Comment: @polasairam Not only you can, but you *must* have a botid to use Pandorabots: `factory.create(ChatterBotType.PANDORABOTS, "b0dafd24ee35a477")`

Comment: @Pierre-DavidBelanger jsut wanted to point out that you cannot be contacted on github unless someone is reporting an error. Maybe setup a discord? Anyway, I though you might want contribute to [this](https://github.com/pierredavidbelanger/chatter-bot-api/releases "ChattBotAPI") part of your project.

Comment: @CardinalSystem I am not sure I understand what you mean. Just open an issues (https://github.com/pierredavidbelanger/chatter-bot-api/issues) and ask your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will be interesting: https://sourceforge.net/projects/chatem/ - script asks to choose 2 chat-bots, starts dialogs and palms off bot's answers from one to another, showing as a dialog

Answer (score 1):

AIML(Pandora Bots)

The original code you get, has a button on the same page where you generate your user key and app id. Once you install pb-cli in usr/bin, compile and set up the program, you can train the bot from your mac terminal or linux shell server side and use pb upload to upload aiml files updating your Pandora Bots knowledge base. After every update you must recompile but the websites have the information strewn across different websites, so if you see any tutorials I would advise you book mark the page. I think the tutorial for nodejs is on chatbots.io

The app name and botname can be anything you want them to be. The host name can be left blank, but I believe it gives use of a url for instance if you wanted to use it on your own website. The name you choose for your bot is a private name that must be used with the other credentials and once it's hosted on Pandora Bots you choose another name, so just use the same name or you will use up your bot allowance. Once pb init is used the underlying bot name you chose will be set.

Once all of this is done you can get on github and download aim files. I have a basic java implementation of the program that I will be working on soon also with OpenGL bindings and eventually I could incorporate Microsoft Kinect technology with JOGL and possibly build a robot one day.